# more than one 'www' folder with wamp

Tags: wamp

Actually I have one website in *c:/wamp/www* path.

But now I want to manage a bunch of websites, I can create the filesystem hierarchy in www with a folder for each website. But the problem is 'document_root' variable is always referring to *c:/wamp/www*

```
SCRIPT_FILENAME : c:/wamp/www/website1/index.php
DOCUMENT_ROOT   : c:/wamp/www
while I'd like  : c:/wamp/www/website1
```

Can I create a folder in wamp folder and refer to it when typing its URI in my browser ?

e.g.

```
http://localhost/ -> c:/wamp/www/index.html
http://website1/  -> c:/wamp/www/website1/index.php
```

thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use multiple `VirtualHost`s (one for each host name) and use a distinct document root in each of them.

More details are available here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @Bruno thanks for your answer, I'm in some troubles, I defined my virtual hosts as written in the link. when I reboot wamp it doesn't seem to work, and even the localhost is not founded. Have you got an idea ?

Comment: It may depend on the DNS entries too. The host name you're trying to use (say `website1.example` in `http://website1.example/`) needs to point to your machine (presumably the same as `localhost` if you're only trying from your machine). If it's just for local tests, you should be able to edit the [host file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29); if you want it accessible for other machines, you need to make sure the DNS entry points to your machine's (publicly visible) IP address.

Comment: i've changed my host file with the right syntax. It seems the error is coming from httpd.conf, if I define a new virtual host with the specific tags and save the file, on reboot I can't access any address (localhost, website1.example, ...) I read apache support but well now I'm not sure where to place `<VirtualHost>`

Comment: It would be useful to see what you get in the Apache Httpd error logs.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I peeped the error log and found out apache wasn't finding the document_root of the virtualhost defined. I've had to type it raw (`c:/wamp/www/website1`). But it's got a bit of a strange for on all the examples that i've seen on the web no one is referring the document root in absolute. Also I've had to Virtualhosting the localhost address ... but anyway it seems to work fine, if you have any suggestion or feedback feel free to embed :)

Comment: I guess most of the examples are for unix-based Apache Httpd. A path beginning with `/` is an absolute path in the unix world (no letters).

Comment: I'm such a fool, you're right. I thought the document_root definition was starting from wamp path. thanks @Bruno

Answer (score 1):

I usually create multiple virtual hosts for my projects:
add the following lines to C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf

```
Listen 9191
NameVirtualHost *:9191

<VirtualHost *:9191>
    ServerName web1.local
    DocumentRoot "D:\VanCK\Projects\Web1\trunk\public_html"
    <Directory "D:\VanCK\Projects\Web1\trunk\public_html"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 9292
NameVirtualHost *:9292

<VirtualHost *:9292>
    ServerName web2.local
    DocumentRoot "D:\VanCK\Projects\Web2\trunk\public_html"
    <Directory "D:\VanCK\Projects\Web2\trunk\public_html"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

add the following lines to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

127.0.0.1    web1.local

127.0.0.1    web2.local

enable rewrite_module (click on WAMP icon > Apache > Apache modules > check rewrite_module)
restart all services

=> http://web1.local:9191/ and http://web2.local:9292/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

after :

AllowOverride All

Order Allow,Deny

Allow From all